# How to get the reverse of a many to many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model for articles with various attributes like author, title, etc. One of the attributes is "comments_on" for all of the articles that the article in question (let's call it "main article" for now) is responding to. 
I use a reciprocal many-to-many relationship to represent this.

I know how to display on a website all of the articles that the main article  comments on. I would like to know if it's possible to display all of the articles **that have commented on** the main article.

I assume I don't need to create a separate field in my model for this, since the relationship between the main article and other articles that comment on the main article is reflected in the same reciprocal many-to-many relationship.

Any idea what the code for this is will be? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name).